# How to calculate online seconds per time interval based on login/logout records in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, logging, sum

I have a table that contains logins and logouts of different users:

```
login   event_date                  event
------------------------------------------
user1   2016-09-16 20:14:28.412830  LOGIN
user1   2016-09-16 20:34:38.937436  LOGOUT
user1   2016-09-16 20:36:34.363710  LOGIN
user1   2016-09-16 21:07:39.470257  LOGOUT
user1   2016-09-16 21:14:37.849903  LOGIN
...
user2   2016-09-16 00:05:02.937110  LOGOUT
user2   2016-09-16 15:00:36.478966  LOGIN
user2   2016-09-16 16:25:01.294783  LOGOUT
user2   2016-09-16 16:30:19.965582  LOGIN
user2   2016-09-16 20:35:04.926386  LOGOUT
...
user3   2016-09-16 11:05:12.818579  LOGIN
user3   2016-09-16 14:42:02.487888  LOGOUT
user3   2016-09-16 14:54:50.574649  LOGIN
user3   2016-09-16 16:00:01.106796  LOGOUT
user3   2016-09-16 17:09:31.366645  LOGIN
user3   2016-09-16 17:25:39.470333  LOGOUT
```

*Note: data in this table is naturally ordered by `event_date` (or rather by `id`); ordering by `login` is provided for convenience.*

I need to calculate each user's online time per time interval (e.g. each 30 mintues, hour, day, etc) and per day of week.

The output I need is something like this:

```
login   hour                 seconds_online
-------------------------------------------
user1   2016-09-16 20:00:00  1920
user1   2016-09-16 21:00:00  420
...
user2   2016-09-16 00:00:00  302
user2   2016-09-16 15:00:00  3564
user2   2016-09-16 16:00:00  1490
...
user3   2016-09-16 11:00:00  3285
user3   2016-09-16 12:00:00  3600  <- Please note how these two lines
user3   2016-09-16 13:00:00  3600  <- relate to the actual log above.
user3   2016-09-16 14:00:00  1078
...
```

Or:

```
login   day_of_week  seconds_online
-----------------------------------
user1   Monday       17280
user1   Tuesday      16540
...
user2   Monday       16990
user2   Tuesday      17014
...
```

Please help!

Comment: Solved by implementing a loop over these records in an external script and calculating online time there.